# Can't find cluster-local-gateway in istio-system namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, knative

I'm using Knative to deploy serverless applications in K8s, recently I experienced that cluster-local-gateway is missing from istio-system namespace, Is there any reason for this..? I'm afraid that in the latest versions istio removed it or, It has to be done by Knative side.
FYI - I do my deployments in GCP enabling istio. I do not manually installed the istio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cluster local gateway need to be installed as part of knative installation. Since you are using GKE to install istio instead of using helm you need to install it manually.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knative/serving/master/third_party/${VERSION}/istio-knative-extras.yaml
```

here VERSION is istio version i.e `istio-1.5.0`

https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/master/third_party/istio-1.5.0/istio-knative-extras.yaml